# Functional doesn't reach its norm

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

I'm trying to prove that for $X=L_1([0,1])$ and the linear functional $\phi(f)=\int_0^1tf(t)dt$, the linear functional doesn't reach its norm.

I already figured out that $\|\phi\|\leq1$, however I don't know how to go about proving that here is no function $f\in B_X$ for which $\phi(f)=1.$
Any help is very welcome.

Comment: @AnneBauval Yes, that is more in line with the solution I was thinking of, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result can be generalized and no advanced theorems are needed. Let $g\neq 0$ be a continuous function on $[0,1].$ The norm of the  functional $$ \varphi(f)=\int\limits_0^1f(x)g(x)\,dx$$ is equal $\displaystyle m:=\max_{0\le x\le 1}|g(x)|.$ Assume the norm is attained at $f,$ $\|f\|_1=1.$ Then $$m=\left |\int\limits_0^1f(x)g(x)\,dx\right |\le \int\limits_0^1|f(x)|\,|g(x)|\,dx\le m$$ Thus
$\displaystyle m=\int\limits_0^1|f(x)|\,|g(x)|\,dx.$ Hence
$$\int\limits_0^1|f(x)|[m-|g(x)|]\,dx =0$$ The integrand is nonnegative thus $$f(x)[m-|g(x)|]=0,\quad {\rm a.e.}$$ Therefore $f(x)=0$ a.e. on the open set $\{x\,:\, |g(x)|<m\}.$ Hence $f$ is concentrated on the closed set $B:=\{x\,:\, |g(x)|=m\}.$ In particular if $B$ is finite the function $f$ is equal $0$ a.e. In the OP case $B$ consists of one point $x=1.$

Answer (score 2):

Assume $f$ is such that $\|f\|_{L^1}=1$ and $\phi(f)=1$.
Take $s\in (0,1)$. Then
$$\begin{split}
1 &= \int_0^1 t f(t) \le \int_0^1 t |f(t)|\\&= \int_0^s t |f(t)| + \int_s^1 t |f(t)|\\
&\le s \int_0^s  |f(t)| + \int_s^1  |f(t)| \\&= s \|f\|_{L^1} + (1-s) \|f\|_{L^1(s,1)}.
\end{split}$$
This implies $\|f\|_{L^1(s,1)}=1$ for all $s$. But $\lim_{s\to1}\|f\|_{L^1(s,1)}=0$ by dominated convergence.